# How to make Alt-h work in Org mode in Spacemacs?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-table

When inside a table in Org mode, I can press Alt-l to move the column to the right.

But alt-h does nothing.

The same happens when  I try to put the heading one level deeper. Alt-l works but alt-h doesn't, meaning I can add asterisks to the header with alt-l but the opposite is not possible.

How to make it that alt-h works in Spacemacs?

Comment: You should be able to do things like that with `M-<right>` and `M-<left>`, where `M` stands for the `Meta` key (usually the left `Alt` key if your keyboard is anything like mine) and `<right>` is the Right-Arrow key (similarly for left). Of course, spacemacs might be using these keybindings for other purposes (I don't use it, so I don't know), but it's worth trying, if only to have an alternative way to do things.  So, not a direct answer to your question but I hope it might help with your problem.

Comment: I know I can do it with alt and arrows. I am curious why not alt-h. For tables, I have found a workaround with `SPC m t H` to move the coIumn to the left, but I will remap it to alt-h because it's too cumbersome, I will try the same for headers. But I am curious why it is not a default setting. Do you have any idea why alt-l yes and alt-h not? As far as I can see there is nothing that uses this alt-h combination.

Comment: What does `C-h c M-i` say in an Org mode buffer? What about `C-h c M-h`?